# Where do I input Facebook's recovery codes?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

I don't have any problem with my account at all, all 100% fine. I'm just trying to TEST [the recovery codes of this page](https://www.facebook.com/security/2fac/settings/).  When clicking on "show codes", I can see the 10 alphanumeric two word codes clearly. However, I can't find any place to input them.

If I go to incognito mode (to not get log-in automatically) and then to the Facebook login screen in the desktop or on Android Chrome.
Where do I put them?
In the password field?
If so, what do I put in the username field?

Desktop: If the correct way is to click on "Forgot account", and then use them to reset password, as it says when you continue that path, then that's bad, because, I don't want to reset my password. Now, [Facebook says clearly in the page linked before](https://www.facebook.com/security/2fac/settings/):

> "Use these codes for when you don't have your phone with you, for
>   example when you're traveling."

Nowhere at all there says anything about password change. So Facebook is being inconsistent in what this "recovery codes" are for.

Mobile browser (Chrome on Android):  I only see username, password, "forgot password", that I don't want to click for the same reason as before.

Facebook Android app: same problem, where to input it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recovery codes are used for [2 Factor Authentication](https://www.facebook.com/help/148233965247823) if you don't have your phone. So after you log into Facebook on a new device, you would enter the recovery code instead of the code that gets SMSed to you (or you get out of an authenticator app like Google Authenticator).

These aren't to be confused with the security code that gets sent via email or SMS when going through the account recovery process if you forget your password.

Comment: Thank you. 1) So, to the title question "Where do I input facebook's recovery codes?" your answer implies, that MUST be a NEW device? Can't I test it on my old devices, it's impossible, even on incognito mode? 2) "So after you log into Facebook on a new device," so, that means to test it, I must introduce username and password. THEN, only if the device is not recognized, will I have a screen asking for recovery codes. right?

Comment: In theory incognito should be enough (typically cookies would be used to track a device), but Facebook may well have built in enough checks that it still recognises the device.

Comment: I just tried incognito, it ALMOST worked. It sent me a SMS, there was another option to do "other ways to sign in" or something like that, but i inserted the sms to see what happened, and it entered well. So, i wanted then, to log out, but when i tried now this thing that says "other ways to sign in", instead it logged me automatically, EVEN ON INCOGNITO! facebook it's too good at detecting me. Maybe another browser or delete cookies and it will work again.

Comment: In summary my best attempt is: Log in to facebook, from my normal pc, but on incognito, and in another browser. Insert username and password, then it sends a sms, WE DONT INSERT THAT CODE, we choose "Need another way to authenticate?", then pops window saying look at your phone facebook's app, click on "code generator". THEN APP CRASHES.

Comment: @Santropedro the recovery code is used in place of the SMS code, you don't need to use the "Need another way to authenticate?"

Comment: What you just said, it worked! I was baffled, since the text says "Two-Factor Authentication Required
You’ve asked us to require a 6-digit login code when anyone tries to access your account from a new device or browser.
Enter the 6-digit code from your Code Generator or 3rd party app below." This  confuses me, since i would expect here, to be offered also the possibility you just told me. I'm baffled also because the recovery codes are 10 characters (in two sets of 5) , not 6 characters! Anyway, thank you very much. There is still to resolve the issue that my app crashes.

Comment: Glad it worked! The codes from your phone/app are time sensitive, they stop working after a few minutes. Since the recovery codes are long lived, they need to be longer to remain secure.

Comment: Ah right, I understand and agree with that.

Comment: I did what produced the crash before, and it didn't now. Now it works! I uninstalled and reinstalled the facebook app, and 2 days after, for some reason now works.

Answer (score 2):

John C's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122007/87130) is incorrect. There is no way to access your account if you have two-part authentication on and have lost your phone. Period. The recovery codes are eight-digit. Authentication codes are six. If you input recovery code (any of the ten) into the two-part authentication box, you will get an error:

> "The login code doesn't match the one sent to your phone..."

You can submit a request via the link in the box "need another way to authenticate" but you must submit a picture ID, then the email you get back is one to reset your password. Once you do that, it goes back to the two-part authentication box and you're back where you started. So..., if you lose the phone that you set up two-part authentication with, you will NEVER be able to access your Facebook account again. Start another account.

Comment: This is my experience as well. I also didn't find any documentation on their site which explains what to do with those code.